# go get installation from a local fork

Tags: go, goinstall, go-get

I am trying to install a go package from a local directory (basically I checked out and existing package and applied a pending pull request).

```
$ # Both commands give a similar output
$ go get -u file:///Users/me/workspaces/go/somepackage
$ go get -u /Users/me/workspaces/go/somepackage
unrecognized import path "[...]" (import path does not begin with hostname)
```

Since `go get` is downloading then installing, I tried:

```
$ go install /Users/me/workspaces/go/somepackage
[] cannot import absolute path
```

Any experienced go user could give a hand?

Comment: Are you trying to install a main package, or a dependency? If it's a `main` package, just cd into it an install it, there's nothing to `go get`. If it's a dependency, it should either already be in GOPATH, or use `replace` in `go.mod`. Packages are never referred to with a local path.

Answer (score 1):

If you just want to use a different branch (your PR branch), you can continue using the original import path.

- Go get the original package first.
- Go into the downloaded package in your local file system `cd $GOPATH/pkg/<package directory>`
- From your local package cache, switch to the branch you want to pull from. `git checkout <PR branch>`
- Now `go get -u <package>`

If the package is available locally, go get update will just pull the latest code from the branch your local package is checked out to.

Comment: I have ended installing another package as the original package was also broken on install. But this seems to be an answer to my question (+1).

Answer (score 0):

As far as I know you can't do this with `go get`, bur you can copy the directory in to GOPATH manually. If you forked `example.com/somepackage` then copy `/Users/me/workspaces/go/somepackage` to `~/go/src/example.com/somepackage` or `./vendor/example.com/somepackage`.

That being said, the best solution is usually to host the forked code somewhere, and then use that import path.  Decency tools such as dep and modules support fetching a different origin for packages.

Comment: but this will be skipping any dependency installation if I am correct.

Answer (score 0):

I could be wrong and maybe there is a workaround exists

Go documentantion on [cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths](https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Remote_import_paths) says:

> The supported version control systems are:
>
> ```
> Bazaar      .bzr
> Fossil      .fossil
> Git         .git
> Mercurial   .hg
> Subversion  .svn
> ```

And a later:

> For example,

`import "example.org/pkg/foo"`

> will result in the following requests:

```
https://example.org/pkg/foo?go-get=1 (preferred)
http://example.org/pkg/foo?go-get=1  (fallback, only with -insecure)
```

So I suppose that `go get` never looks in filesystem repos.

Need to investigate source code of `go get` to be sure.

I will be glad if someone will prove that I am incorrect in this question.

### UPDATE

Maybe I'm mistaken but I suppose that all abilities of `go get` to work with VCSs are here: https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/cmd/go/internal/get/vcs.go

And I don't see here a possibility to work with git local repos.